# How are static constructors and private constructors different?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

How are static constructors and private constructors different?

```
public class WorkstationDevicePresenter
{
    private WorkstationDevicePresenter()
    {}
}
```

What's the point in leaving them blank?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Whats the point in leaving them blank?

There are a number of reasons to make "blank" constructors.

You might make a blank constructor because you want a place to set a breakpoint during debugging.

You might make a blank static constructor because doing so changes the semantics of static field initializers. Read [Jon's article on the subject](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx) for details.

Let's leave static constructors and consider blank instance constructors.

The key rule that motivates blank constructors is: By default if there are no constructors in a type then you get a "blank" parameterless public constructor for free. If there are any constructors in a type then you do not get a blank parameterless public constructor for free.

So the first obvious reason why you'd want a blank constructor is: I want a blank parameterless constructor, but I've already made another ctor, so I no longer get one for free.

The second reason is that you don't have any ctors and you do not want a blank parameterless *public* constructor. You might want a blank parameterless private, internal or protected constructor. If that's what you want then you'll have to make one yourself.

In particular, making an empty private ctor as the only ctor means that the class cannot be instantiated via a constructor from outside the class. This is very useful if you want to use the factory pattern. It also prevents code outside the class from making derived classes, because derived classes must be able to call a constructor. If all the constructors are private then they can't derive.

I frequently use this variation on the factory pattern:

```
public abstract class Thing
{
  private Thing() {}
  private class RedThing : Thing { ... }
  public static Thing GetRedThing() { return new RedThing(); }
}
```

See, by making a private constructor I can make a public abstract class that can only be instantiated by *my code* and only extended by *my code*, and therefore I have a nice invariant: every time I see an object of type `Thing`, I know where it came from.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure that having a private constructor would stop the class from getting a _default_ constructor...

Comment: @Lucas: If a class has any instance constructor in source code then it does not get the default constructor.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: The point is that it prevents derivation *except by nested classes*. The "abstract" is redundant; it's just there to make the code more self-documenting.

Comment: @EricLippert yes, I've never used it for such restrictions. Thanks for sharing this pattern and making code more explicit.

Comment: There is another more pragmatic "reason" to explicitly add a blank constructor, instead of relaying on the compiler to provide one. It makes it easier (less clicks) to use Resharper's "Find Usages" and see where the instance of the class is created (of course except by deserialization/reflection).

Answer (score 2):

Static constructors happen once when the class is loaded, private constructors happen when they are called by some public static method typically used to create singletons, or with the Builder pattern.  There is no reason to have a blank private constructor (that I know of).

Comment: There are a number of reasons to have an empty private ctor.

Comment: @EricLippert, would you mind enumerating one or two.  I'm genuinely interested...

Comment: See my answer for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Static constructors initialize the static parts of a class and private constructors can only be used by the class itself, like for creating a singleton-object of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

    private static int staticitem;
    private int instanceitem;

    static MyClass(){
        staticitem = 0; //define value for staticitem
    }

    private MyClass() { //can only be called from within the class
       instanceitem = 0; //define value for instanceitem
    }

    public static MyClass GetMyClass() {
       MyClass m = new MyClass();
       return m;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Blank private constructor will make the class uninstantiable by anything other than itself. If you don't have this piece of code, by default the compiler creates a blank **public** parameterless contstructor.

Static constructor is called when creating the static instance.

You can use both to create a Singleton pattern, for instance.

Check the following code:

```
public class Singleton
{
    public static Singleton Instance;
    static Singleton
    {
        Instance = new Singleton();
    }
    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public static Singleton CompileError = new Singleton();
    public static Singleton CompileOK = Singleton.Instance;
}
```

Comment: Is this true?  If you have a blank private constructor and a non-blank public constructor, would it be uninstantiable?

Comment: "by anything other than itself". Should've been more specific.